Variation of the metric on Kähler quotient
We can use Kähler quotient to produce a family of Kähler metrics on quotient space.
My question is: how do we calculate the variation of these metric?
This seems to be a natural question but I can't find any explicitly resolution online. Can somebody give me some advice or references for this question? Thanks!
